# Why are my alacritty vim colors different than iterm2?

Tags: alacritty

I’ve swithced from iterm2 to alacritty. However I noticed that although I’m using the same vim color scheme ([gruvbox](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox)), they colors appear different (especially the dark gray), notice the difference:

**Iterm2**

[image]

**Alacritty**

[image]

(notice how the comment for example in alacritty is more purplish)

Here is my iTerm2 [color config](https://gist.github.com/abbood/0a1ebbd439a92a5dc230b58ea82f583e), and here is my alacritty color config:

```
window:
  padding:
    x: 10
    y: 10

key_bindings:
  - { key: Return,   mods: Command,         action: ToggleSimpleFullscreen }

import:
 - ~/.config/alacritty/themes/themes/base16_default_dark.yaml

font:
  normal:
    family: HackNerdFontCompleteNerdFont Nerd Font 
    style:  Regular
  bold:
    family: Hack Nerd Font 
    style:  Bold
  italic:
    family: Hack Nerd Font 
    style:  Italic
  bold_italic:
    family: Hack Nerd Font 
    style: Bold Italic
  size: 14

selection:
  save_to_clipboard: true

draw_bold_text_with_bright_colors: true
```

were I imported the color theme from [here](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty-theme).

## update

this isn’t specific to gruvbox. I switched the color theme to spacegray and the difference was there as well:

iterm2
[image]

alacritty
[image]

## update 2

I think the culprit is tmux, when i run the above without running tmux, things work fine. I’m trying to figure out what’s the setting in my tmux that’s breaking things

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is [this step](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/INSTALL.md#terminfo)

```
sudo tic -xe alacritty,alacritty-direct extra/alacritty.info
```

after locally cloning the [alacritty repo](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty)

then i put this in ~/.tmux.conf

```
set -sg terminal-overrides ",*:RGB”
```

I got inspired by this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1772039/234141)

tip of the day: don’t go around mindlessly copying and pasting solutions from the web, understand the problem first and the solution will *jump* at you